# Parameters cannot be resolved in servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am tryin to get the credentials from jsp page-index.jsp
In my servlet-LoginServletwhen under package dao i use

```
String userName = request.getParameter(usrnm_gtalk);
String password = request.getParameter(password_gtalk);
```

it says `usrnm_gtalk` and `password_gtalk` cannot be resolved.

in my jsp

```
<form name="LoginForm" method="post" action="/dao/LoginServlet>   
<input type="text" name="usrnm_gtalk"/>
<input type="password" name="password_gtalk" />
```

web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>dao.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

i have the servlet-api jar in the lib as well as build path

can anyone point out wat is the problem
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to represent them as strings, with doublequotes, not as non-existing variables (as the compiler is trying to tell you).

```
String userName = request.getParameter("usrnm_gtalk"); 
String password = request.getParameter("password_gtalk");
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)
- [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains a little hello world