# Servlets-requested resource not found

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have `index.jsp` from which I get the parameters to servlet `LoginServlet.java`
The servlet is under package dao.

```
<form name="LoginForm" method="post" action="dao/LoginServlet">
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Chat</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>dao.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I run the JSP page I can see it but I get an error telling

```
The requested resource (dao/LoginServlet) is not available
```

Can anyone point out wat is the problem?

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527478/parameters-cannot-be-resolved-in-servlets This isn't very fair. Even though this might have been a very embarrassing mistake of yourself, I wouldn't really appreciate that my effort in posting the answer has turned out to be a total waste. Dumb questions doesn't exit on Stackoverflow. Bad questions do and they don't deserve to be answered. Yours wasn't bad at all.

Comment: i deleted bcoz i was able to correct the error after posting the question.would not be fair to bother once i get the ans...hey sorry i din see u had posted ur question... MY apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form action should point to the servlet URL as specified in `<url-pattern>` entry of its `<servlet-mapping>` in `web.xml`. You have declared the servlet to listen on `Login`, but this is actually invalid. It should start with a slash.

```
<url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
```

This way it listens on http://localhost:8080/yourcontextname/Login.

Then you can just let the form action point to that URL (assuming that the JSP file isn't placed in a subfolder of your webapp context).

```
<form action="Login" method="post">
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlet wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains a little Hello World